# Making Parallax effect workable on iOS

Tags: jquery, parallax

I am making a website. At home page i add a parallax effect and it works well. But in iOS it doesn't work. Here is my simple code

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $(window).bind('scroll', function(e) {
       parallax();
     });
   });

   function parallax() {
     var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
     $('.slideshow').css('top',(0 - (scrollPosition * 0.3)) + 'px' );
   }
</script>
```

Here I have changed the position of the class of the div. But in iOS it doesn't change smoothly. It changes it's position after a few seconds later. That is the problem. Here you can see the problem at http://www.Dwetech.com

How can i make this code workable in iOS ??

Comment: Describe what happens when you say it doesn't work. Does this code do nothing, or not what you expected?

Comment: Here i change the position of the class (div). But in iOS it doesn't change smoothly. It changes it's position after a few seconds later. That is the problem.

Here you can see the problem [Dwetech.com](http://Dwetech.com/)